# Can't run LaTeX on Pi 3

Tags: raspbian

I tried to run LaTeX on a couple documents I'm working on, on my Pi 3, but I get a segmentation fault like this for each file:

```
$ latex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
Segmentation fault
```

Is the default TeX Live package for Raspberry Pi broken? Do I need to build LaTeX from source?

This is on Raspbian Jessie with Pixel.

Comment: My guess is something got half installed. Could you try to run latex inside a debugger ?  It should dump a trace when it crasshes. You can install it with sudo apt-get install gdb. Try running gdb latex, then type r to see if it crashes.